# How to range and sequence in PHP

Tags: php, range, sequence

i need a sequence like this in a **range** from 0 to 10 with PHP. The result would be:

0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
........

I want to insert this function inside a `foreach`

UPDATE

```
<?php $count = 0; ?>
```

```
<div class="<?php echo 'minipost-'. $count++ ; ?>">
<?php
get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried checking [for](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) and [foreach](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) manual pages? Was there anything confusing and/or imcomplete in the description given?

Comment: `<div class="<?php echo 'minipost-'. ($count++ % 10); ?>">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already mentioned the solution in your question. You can use:

```
range(0, 10)
```

To repeat the sequence 3 times you could do:

```
str_repeat(implode(' ',range(0, 10)).' ', 3);
```

Comment: @Rob1n - If you need an infinite sequence, then either increase your memory to infinite; use a Generator; or use a counter and a bit of math like `($i++ % 10)`... explain what you're trying to achieve and we can probably provide a better answer

Answer (score 0):

Without foreach;

```
$iCounter = 2;
$iCount = 10;

for ($k = 1; $k <= $iCounter; $k++) {
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $iCount; $i++) {
        // do anything you need
        echo $i;
    }
}
```